# Find index of all rows with null values in a particular column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have been worried about how to find indices of all rows with null values in a particular column of a pandas dataframe in python. If `A` is one of the entries in `df.columns` then I need to find indices of each row with null values in `A`

Comment: `df[~df.A.isnull()].index`?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Supposing you need the indices as a list, one option would be:

```py
df[df['A'].isnull()].index.tolist()
```

Comment: `df['A'].isnull()` is a Series of booleans, that contains True for each row where the column A is null.
And you can use this series to filter the original dataframe and keep only the specified rows.   
I hope that helps.

Comment: okay if we want an equality condition with the isnull condition i.e. we want all rows with column `B` as `x` and `A` as `null`

Comment: Not sure to understand your question.
`isnull` is a _method_ of pandas.DataFrame and needs to be called the same way as any other method.

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: can you tell me how to make conditions that work insensitively on character strings like `df['a'] == 'get'` so here I want the indices of all rows in column `A` with any combination of get, Get, GET i.e. no sesitivity

Comment: `df['a'].str.lower() == 'get'` should work.
See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html for more details about text data processing.

Answer (score 5):

```
np.where(df['column_name'].isnull())[0]
```

`np.where(Series_object)` returns the indices of `True` occurrences in the column. So, you will be getting the indices where `isnull()` returned `True`.

The `[0]` is needed because `np.where` returns a tuple and you need to access the first element of the tuple to get the array of indices.

Similarly, if you want to get the indices of all non-null values in the column, you can run

```
np.where(df['column_name'].isnull() == False)[0]
```