# Extract the index number of the null value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the index number when the value is null in the column, 
which is the best way to Creating a Function to get the null's index number using pandas?

thanx in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find index of all rows with null values in a particular column in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44869327/find-index-of-all-rows-with-null-values-in-a-particular-column-in-pandas-datafra)

Comment: @CavinDsouza I have tried that function before but it is not working with my data :
`df_final[df_final['District'].isnull()].index.tolist()` and the output is : `[]`

Comment: could you edit your post to share the data frame `df_final`? It could be that what you're referring to as null is an empty string instead. Does, ```df_final[df_final['District'] == ''].index.tolist()``` yield a result?

Comment: @CavinDsouza The result is still same `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a copy of the dataframe, it's difficult to ascertain the problem here, but it should belong to one of the three categories:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Sample data-frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['1', '2', '3', '', ' ', '   ', '5', np.nan]})
```

The column has a NULL value

```
print(df.loc[df['x'].isnull()])

"""
     x
7  NaN
"""
```

The column has an empty string

```
print(df.loc[df['x'] == ''])
"""
  x
3  
"""
```

The column has an empty string or comprises of non-zero number of whitespaces only.

```
print(df.loc[df['x'].str.strip() == ''])
"""
     x
3     
4     
5     
"""
```