# My CSV dataset has no blanks but df.isnull().sum() keeps saying there are null values

Tags: python, pandas, csv, null, dataset

I'm trying to learn how to clean my CSV dataset which has two columns, 'word' & 'misspelling'. The raw dataset comes from `birkbeck.dat`.

When I run `df.isnull().sum()` to check if there is any null value, it tells me there is 1 null value in the column 'misspelling'.

I run `df = df.dropna()` and went to check again with `df.isnull().sum()`, it's still telling me there is 1 null value in the column 'misspelling'.

I also run `df.isnull().values.any()` and it returns 'True'.

**Attempt 1:**

I opened up the CSV dataset in Excel and checked for blanks using 'Find & Select' -> 'Go To Special' but it did not find any.

**Attempt 2:**

I created another CSV dataset that shows 'TRUE' or 'FALSE'  using `df.isnull()` to check which rows & columns have data that could be detected as null:

```
df_null = df.isnull()

csv_file = 'null_data.csv'
df_null.to_csv(csv_file, index=False)
```

I opened up this CSV dataset in Excel and searched for 'TRUE' but it did not find any.

**Attempt 3:**

I checked which rows & columns have null through code instead:

```
rows_with_null = df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
columns_with_null = df.columns[df.isnull().any()]

print(rows_with_null)
print(columns_with_null)
```

Both returned no indexes which means it did not detect any null values.

Comment: In the spirit of [mre] and [ask], rather than indicating some obscure dataset, please share a representative sample of the csv and the corresponding dataframe rows, possibly using `print(df.to_dict())`

Comment: Also this shold help. Instead of bothering to write a csv and explore it, why not stay within Python and use and upvote this: [Find index of all rows with null values in a particular column in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44869327/12846804)